# Moments of $|ax-by|$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, random-variables, uniform-distribution

> Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independentr.v. uniform on $[0,1]$.

What is the $E[|aX-bY|^p]$ for some constants $a,b,p>0$?

**What I did.**

\begin{align*}
E[|aX-bY|^p]=\int_0^1\int_0^1|ax-by|^p dx dy
\end{align*}

For the case p=1. I  can show that $E[|aX-bY|]=\frac{b^2}{3a}+\frac{a-b}{2}$ if $b \le a$ and  $E[|aX-bY|]=\frac{a^2}{3b}+\frac{b-a}{2}$.  For, the case $p>1$ the intgration becomes difficult (at least for me).
I also think an lower bound on it will suffice for my purposes.

Is this an way to solve this? Also, is this something that is commonly encountered in probability?

Comment: The problem just says that $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables. Did you mean to say they have the uniform distribution?

Comment: yes. forgot. will add. thanks

Comment: What about their independence?

Comment: yes. they are independent. I will  add it the statement. Thanks.